Electronic transport calculations With Transiesta and Spin-Orbit
What is the version of SIESTA that is capable of performing transport calculations with TranSIESTA, including spin-orbit coupling?

+1. Welcome to our community!

None, currently transiesta does not enable spin-orbit or non-collinear transport. Only spin polarised calculations are possible.
There is however plans to add this feature, however it may take some time :)
